# Using Capybara to select multiple objects created by Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, factory-bot

I am using Raild 3.2.11, Capybara 2.0.2 and Factory Girl 4.1.0.

I am trying to select multiple users in a form using Capybara. However it looks like my users are not being created. The views work fine and I can select multiple users if I use Rails Server. Somehow it log in the last created instance, Joe_4.

I am getting this error for my tests:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find option "Joe_1"
```

**Factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :nickname do |n|
     "Joe_#{n}"
  end

  sequence :email do |e|
     "joe_#{e}@kebas.com"
  end

  factory :player, :aliases =>
       [:first_pair_1st_player, :first_pair_2nd_player,
       :second_pair_1st_player, :second_pair_2nd_player] do
     nickname              
     email                 
     password              "password"
     password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

**Features/match_test_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Entered matched results" do

before :each do
  4.times do 
   FactoryGirl.create(:player)
  end
end

context "should fail when," do 

  it "the score are the same" do
    visit root_path
    valid_player_login
    click_link "New Match"
    select('Joe_1', :from => 'doubles_match_first_pair_1st_player_id')
    select('Joe_2', :from => 'doubles_match_first_pair_2nd_player_id')
    select('Joe_3', :from => 'doubles_match_second_pair_1st_player_id')
    select('Joe_4', :from => 'doubles_match_second_pair_1st_player_id')
    fill_in "doubles_match_first_pair_score",   :with => "14"
    fill_in "doubles_match_second_pair_score",  :with => "14"
    click_link_or_button "Game Over"
    page.should have_content("Match can't end with the same score")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was that I had spork running. When I stopped it - everything worked. Read more here:

[Why not use shared ActiveRecord connections for Rspec + Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium)