# Ajax comments testing with Rspec

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Hello i have a problem with Rspec + Capybara. I wanna to test that my ajax comments can be post. My error is because a post doesn't create.

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Could')
```

When i output @post i see

```
#<Post id: 1, title: "Deploying through ssh", body: "This is post about ssh", slug: deploying-through-ssh, published: nil, published_at: nil, created_at: "2013-02-05 17:37:39", updated_at: "2013-02-05 17:37:39", user_id: nil, meta_desc: nil> 

describe "Sending Comments" do
      before(:each) do
        @post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
      end
      it "should allow user to post new comment", :js => true do
        visit post_path(@post)
        page.should have_content('Could')
        fill_in 'comment[name]', :with => "name"
        fill_in 'comment_email', :with => "email@mail.com"
        fill_in 'comment_content', :with => "content"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do the right settings, your test and your server, which is used for the test with selenium (`:js => true`), will use two different database connections and wrap the tests into transactions.
That leads to the situation, that what you see in your test in `@post` is not existing in the browser, since the changes in the transaction is not committed.

You can use a shared connection which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium) or don't use a transactional cleaning strategy. Have a look for the [database-cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner).