# Rspec ignores establish_connection statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I've got a Rails 3.2.11 app with some models set up to use another database with establish_connection. The strange thing is that when running tests Rspec seems to completely ignore another connection, i keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "daily_stats" does not exist
```

My default db is Postgres, but the other one is Mysql. I'm sure its because of Rspec because things work correctly in rails console when I run it in a test env via 'rails c test'

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps someone — it turned out that I forced all ActiveRecord classes to use same shared connection following this answer: [Why not use shared ActiveRecord connections for Rspec + Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium)

Make sure to use separate shared connections for each database.