# Using rspec, zeus and database_cleaner with two different active_record databases ends in undefined method `query_options' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, zeus, database-cleaner

I'd like to use zeus (0.13.3) to preload my rails environment for an rails (3.2.11) app on ruby 2.0.0 and use database_cleaner (0.9.1) to clean the databases.
This is working fine if as long as I use only one mysql database.
In the app we have to use two different mysql databases.
*Edit:* What needs to be mentioned is, that I use the shared connection hack, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium).

Running my specs without using zeus is working like expected. But if I use it, every test is failing in the moment when a record is created with the error:

```
undefined method `query_options' for nil:NilClass
```

How can this be solved?

The setup is like that:

```
config/database.yml

test:
  database: app_test
  ...

test_second_db:
  database: other_test
  ...
```

In an abstract base class for all the models using the second connection we do

```
models/second_db/base.rb

module SecondDB

  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base

    establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_second_db"
    self.abstract_class = true

  end

end
```

In my spec_helper.rb file I setup the database_cleaner:

```
spec/spec_helper.rb

require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_second_db}].strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_second_db}].start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :test_second_db}].clean
  end

end
```

*edit:*

```
spec/support/shared_connection.rb

class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
```

spec/support/shared_connection.rb

Comment: Can you run the test with `--trace`, so I can see an extended backtrace? This might require digging into some code.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by modifying the @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection line to use only one connection in the pool:  ```@@shared_connection || ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(:size => 1) { retrieve_connection }```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will fix your issue as I am not able to test it but you may want to try adding this to your spec_helper file.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.class_eval do
        def current_connection_id
          # Thread.current.object_id
          Thread.main.object_id
        end
end
```

This is used for Selenium when running the browser in tests. Tests use transactions and the browser is a seperate process so it cant see the DB. This may not be the problem/solution but its worth a try.

Comment: Maybe this is an alternative to the shared connection. I have to check it.