# Why are these Rspec examples not occuring within a DB transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm writing a typical test in my application where I create a model through a form and check that the model count equals 1.

The test fails because there are already multiple records in the test DB, and this count increases each time I run my tests. It looks like each example isn't happening inside a transaction (being rolled back) like it's supposed to, and I don't know why.

I have this line in my spec_helper.rb file, which is supposed to run each example in a transaction:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Here is my spec that keeps generating model objects:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Admin artwork pages" do
  subject { page }
  let(:gallery) { FactoryGirl.create(:gallery) }

  describe "artwork creation" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "creates new artwork" do
        visit admin_gallery_artworks_path(gallery_id: gallery.id)

        click_link 'Add new artwork'
        fill_in 'artwork_title', with: 'Still Life'
        click_button 'Create Artwork'

        page.should have_text 'Successfully created'
        Artwork.count.should eq 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the error message from Rspec:

```
Failures:

1) Admin artwork pages artwork creation with valid attributes creates new artwork
 Failure/Error: Artwork.count.should eq 1

   expected: 1
        got: 153

   (compared using ==)
```

Edit: Contents of my spec_helper.rb file:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config| 

# Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

# If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
# examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
# instead of true.
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

# If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
# automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
# rspec-rails.
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

# Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
# order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
# the seed, which is printed after each run.
#     --seed 1234
config.order = "random"
# Include route helpers
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
#
# Take the FactoryGirl out of FactoryGirl.create
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

end

I'm using Rails 4.0.0.rc1, Ruby 1.9.3, FactoryGirl and rspec-rails 2.13.0 Thanks for any help.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The Sqlite3 that Rails comes with.

Comment: Are you using fixtures?

Comment: Can you paste your `spec_helper.rb` file too?

Comment: Also does this get fixed by running `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: @AaronK No to fixtures, using FactoryGirl. Posted my spec_helper.rb file. I ran db:test:prepare just in case I forgot to sync the test DB, made no difference. Arg!

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that Rails 4 is supported starting in rspec-rails 2.13.1 - I was using 2.13.0. After upgrading, the specs took place within a transaction like they were supposed to.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to post help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the way you have your test written and less to due with `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`. Focus on the bottom of the error that says `(compared using ==)`

Try to use the expecting change rspec syntax instead

Change this:

```
  click_button 'Create Artwork'

  page.should have_text 'Successfully created'
  Artwork.count.should eq 1
```

To this:

```
  expect { click_button 'Create Artwork' }.to change { Artwork, :count }.by(1)

  page.should have_text 'Successfully created'
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're running a request spec: when you call visit the code under test is run in a server instance (in the same process). In particular this means that it's using a different thread.

As a result the application code ends up using a different database connection, and since transactions are a per connection thing there is no transaction used when your controller inserts records into the database.

There are several ways to address this. One is to abandon rspec's transactional fixtures and use the database_cleaner gem. You can set it up so that controller and model specs use transactions but request specs use truncate to forcibly clear out tables.

Another approach is to try and force both the spec code and the server code to use the same database connection, this eliminating the problem. You can see this approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium). In my experience this works pretty well until you start using a capybara driver such as poltergeist which will run any javascript on the page and your page fires ajax requests.

The approach I've been using is to set the active record connection pool size to 1: there is only 1 connection allowed so everyone will use the same one. You do then have to do some work to ensure that connections are returned to the pool or your spec just hangs.

I wrote up the details a while ago as a [blog post](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/8/18/threading-the-rat/), but in a nutshell you need to

- call `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` before calling methods like visit, click and so on
- hack config.middleware.insert_before `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement` so that it clears the connection after each request (by default it doesn't do this in tests).