# Test BrainTree with rspec and capybara in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails, braintree

I'm working on a Rails 4 app and i want to write some tests for BrainTree:

using rspec-rails (2.14.0) and capybara (2.1.0) in Rails 4.0.0

The problem is with on the route, in the form for Braintree i pass a :url

```
<%= form_for :customer, :url => Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url do |f| %>
```

Now when i run a feature test like this one:

```
  it 'should make new payment info' do

    login

    visit new_customer_path

    page.fill_in 'customer_credit_card_number', :with => '4111111111111111'
    page.fill_in 'customer_credit_card_expiration_date', :with => '01/25'
    page.fill_in 'customer_credit_card_cvv', :with => '400'
    page.click_button 'Save Payment Info'

    page.should have_content('Payment Info Confirmation')
    page.should have_content('411111******1111')
  end
```

i get a error on the route:

```
    Failure/Error: page.click_button 'Save Payment Info'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [POST] "/merchants/fvn6vfc5ptyg2xrp/transparent_redirect_requests"
```

I've also tried this in a controller test (with render_views):

```
  it 'should make new payment info' do
    sign_in_as_user

    visit new_customer_path

    page.fill_in 'customer_credit_card_number', :with => '4111111111111111'
    page.fill_in 'customer_credit_card_expiration_date', :with => '01/25'
    page.fill_in 'customer_credit_card_cvv', :with => '400'
    page.click_button 'Save Payment Info'
    save_and_open_page
   page.should have_content('Payment Info Confirmation')
   page.should have_content('411111******1111')
  end
```

Same error on the route...

In development env in the browser it works fine, i looks like the :url option in my form gets ignored by capybara? I wonder if anybody can help me with this?

I've also found these examples apps for Braintree with Rails: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby_examples/blob/master/rails3_tr_devise/spec/controllers/customer_controller_spec.rb when i run the tests on that project it works.. maybe my problem has to do with the version of Rails and rspec?

many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually cover this exact scenario in my [Multitenancy with Rails](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails) book.

The difference between your tests and Braintree's project's tests are that your tests are Capybara features and theirs' are controller specs.

I mention [this relevant part of Capybara's README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#racktest) within the book:

> RackTest is Capybara's default driver. It is written in pure Ruby and does not
>   have any support for executing JavaScript. Since the RackTest driver interacts
>   directly with Rack interfaces, it does not require a server to be started.
>   However, this means that if your application is not a Rack application (Rails,
>   Sinatra and most other Ruby frameworks are Rack applications) then you cannot
>   use this driver. **Furthermore, you cannot use the RackTest driver to test a
>   remote application, or to access remote URLs (e.g., redirects to external sites,
>   external APIs, or OAuth services) that your application might interact with.**

The way I get around it is that I  wrote a gem called `fake_braintree_redirect` which inserts a piece of middleware into the request stack during the test environment to capture these requests and respond appropriately. The middleware is added to the stack using an `initializer` block defined within `application.rb`, like this:

```
initializer 'middleware.fake_braintree_redirect' do
  if Rails.env.test?
    require 'fake_braintree_redirect'
    config.middleware.use FakeBraintreeRedirect
  end
end
```

This takes Braintree out of the equation completely and returns a successful response whenever you send data to it.

---

Alternatively, if you *really* want to test against Braintree's sandbox, you could switch to the JavaScript driver by tagging your `scenario` as:

```
 scenario "foo", :js => true
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for your answer! The cool thing is that i have your book (bought it on 19 jan) but haven't looked in to it lately. I will you use your gem because i was also looking at the [link]https://github.com/thoughtbot/fake_braintree to speed up the tests. But what i don't get is that my controller test also doesn't work like the one in the braintree example but my controller test is exactly the same! adding :js => true with selenium driver gives me weird sqlite errors at this moment :(

Comment: About the selenium driver and the sqlite error, i've fix that forcing all the drivers using the same connection [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium. The things you need to do for some tests...