# How to select an option in Rails/Capybara/Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

The 'select' method (part of Capybara DSL) doesn't work under ':js => true', but it works otherwise. I am trying to test adding/removing items between two select boxes in Rspec, so need to trigger javascript associated with the clicking of 'Add' and 'Remove' buttons.

It's not stated anywhere in Capybara's document that its DSL will not work with ':js => true' (which enables a javascript driver - in my case the default Selenium). Another way to tackle the issue might be to do the clicking through Selenium, but I could not find any document, especially in the Rails/Rspec/Capybara context.

Can somebody share some examples/links? A complete syntax reference of Capybara/Selenium would be great. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've used `select` with the Selenium driver before with no problem, could you explain exactly what is happening to make you say it 'doesn't work'?

Comment: I've also used capybara select with selenium (configured to use the firefox browser) without any problems.

Comment: I'm having this same issue right now with capybara-webkit so you're not alone.

Comment: Actually, I found the bug in my code through an epic hunt. Well, sort of. My test actually worked with Selenium, and it's possible that I fixed some bug with it during my epic debugging session. With webkit, it actually doesn't appear to change the selected entry, but for some reason, if you put a save_page in the right place, it actually works, and my form is submitted properly. I wonder if your issue has to do with transactional fixtures a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail

Comment: @JonM - Sorry for the late reply. Stackoverflow notification doesn't work! Here is my answer to your question. I'm using save_and_open_page, without ':js=>true', I can see that the item I select is highlighted in the select box; with it, nothing is selected. That's what I meant by "it doesn't work".

Comment: Ugh - How should I at-mention people in stackoverflow?!

Comment: @Ibrahim - could you provide some detailed info about where and how you put save_page? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember where we put it, I think we changed our test cases around. It's a really annoying situation.