# Issue with Capybara request specs with JS - can't find the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm having an issue with JS request specs - basic visiting of a model edit page:

```
it "can edit a doc", :js => true do
  doc = FactoryGirl.create(:doc) # tried with Doc.create as well
  puts Doc.find(doc.id) # 1 <- so it's definitely in the DB!
  visit edit_doc_path(doc) 
end
```

Result: ***"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find doc with id=1"***

The odd thing is it works with standard request spec. I tried both webkit and selenium drivers. My spec_helper looks like this (should be pretty standard):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.before(:each, :type => :request) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
end
```

Rails 3.1.4, no versioning for capybara, rspec, etc. test libraries.

Any input much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove js:true?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have same problem as this:
[Capybara with :js => true causes test to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail)

Try setting DatabaseCleaner strategy to :truncation and see if it works

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```