# Database timeout when running RSpec/Capybara with javascript driver

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to get some RSpec examples working with Capybara using the javascript driver (w/ Webkit or Poltergeist) but there's a locking issue with the database when updating a table. Here's part of the example in question:

```
  scenario 'by changing the contract attributes', js: true do
    login_as @admin, scope: :user

    contract = Contract.create(number: '123',
                               start_at: Date.today,
                               end_at: Date.today + 1.month)

    visit "/contracts/#{contract.id}/edit"
```

I'm using Devise and the `Warden::Test::Helpers` to login.

Running RSpec takes a while and all I get:

```
 Failure/Error: visit "/contracts/#{contract.id}/edit"
 Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
   Unable to load URL: http://127.0.0.1:46520/contracts/1/edit
```

The log is showing that there's a database locking issue:

```
Started GET "/contracts/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-01 12:10:26 -0400
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (51083.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2012-06-01 16:10:26', `current_sign_in_at` = '2012-06-01 16:10:26', `last_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `current_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `sign_in_count` = 1, `updated_at` = '2012-06-01 16:10:26' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2012-06-01 16:10:26', `current_sign_in_at` = '2012-06-01 16:10:26', `last_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `current_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `sign_in_count` = 1, `updated_at` = '2012-06-01 16:10:26' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I've tried lots of things (that question seemed to closest to an actual solution: [Capybara with :js => true causes test to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail)) but nothing worked, even getting rid of DatabaseCleaner. Is there anything else I could try?

**Edit**: Here's the `spec_helper.rb` file as requested: https://gist.github.com/2855631

Comment: Can you post your spec_helper file?

Comment: @DVG I've edited my question with a link to gist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certainly

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Which is trying to run your example inside of a transaction, for the purpose of having clean data. Since you're using Database Cleaner, you already have this feature, so set this to false and you should be good to go.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was so obvious I would have never found it myself! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was just the opposite :)

I have set it to `false`:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

And it all worked. With `true` it wasn't working just as before.