# Guard Executing all specs causes Capybara + JS test to return: 'Rack application timed out during boot'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, guard

I've got a Capybara script with Rsped that includes `:js => true`, script that works fine when I execute the script in isolation. Yay!  Here's the script:

```
# spec/requests/capybara_and_js_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Associating Articles with Menus" do
  it "should include javascript", js: true do
    visit root_path
    page.should have_selector('script')
  end
end
```

When I execute the script I get:

```
.
Finished in 4.22 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

However, when I execute the same script with all of my specs via `Guard Run all`, I get this (I've omitted a couple thousand tests)

```
........................*...*..............Rack application timed out during boot
Rack application timed out during boot
F.....................................
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spend quite a bit of time researching this issue, and found some interesting blog posts on the issue, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here are the options I tried:

I switched from the default js driver for Capybara Selenium to Webkit and Poltergeist, like so:

```
# Gemfile
gem "capybara-webkit"

# spec/spec_helper.rb
Spork.prefork do
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
end
```

and

```
# Gemfile
  gem "poltergeist"

# spec/spec_helper.rb
Spork.prefork do
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

but no luck with either.

Per [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-capybara/XyqV890tsKU) and [this article](http://pullmonkey.com/2011/03/03/rack-application-timed-out-during-boot-capybara/) I tried:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
Spork.prefork do
  Capybara.server_boot_timeout = 600  # Default is 10 my entire suite
end                                   # takes ~550s to run, that's why I
                                      # attempted such a large boot timeout in
                                      # case the time was from beginning of suite 
                                      # execution.
```

To no avail.

Then I found [this article](http://docs.tddium.com/troubleshooting/browser-based-integration-tests), so I attempted:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
# initial advice was for cucumber, and thus recommended this to be placed in
# the features/env.rb file
def find_available_port
  server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 0)
  server.addr[1]
ensure
  server.close if server
end

if ENV['TDDIUM'] then
  Capybara.server_port = find_available_port
end
```

But no luck with that.

I also checked my database_cleaner settings to ensure DatabaseCleaner was playing nicely with my factories from FactoryGirl, [per this issue on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail)

Still no luck.

Next I tried to parse out my capybara tests from my lower level rspec tests in my Guardfile, like so:

```
group 'integration tests' do
  # Capybara Tests
  guard 'rspec', spec_paths: ['spec/requests'] do
    watch(%r{^spec/requests/.+_spec\.rb})
  end  
  # Cucumber Feature Tests
  guard 'cucumber', bundler: true do
    watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  end
end

group 'unit tests' do
  rspec_paths = ['spec/controllers', 'spec/helpers', 'spec/models', 'spec/views']
  # RSpec Unit Tests
  guard 'rspec', spec_paths: rspec_paths do
    watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  end
  # Jasmine JS Unit Tests
  guard 'jasmine', all_on_start: false, all_after_pass: false do
    watch(%r{spec/javascripts/.+_spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})
  end
end
```

and SUCCESS! Finally!

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, after spending lots of time. I figure it out that i am running another rails server on port 3001. When i shutdown that server my cukes are worked like charm.

I hope that will help some one!