# Capybara with poltergeist is failing after the scenario is done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I'm getting a weird error when testing my app using Capybara and poltergeist.

/features/document.feature

```
@javascript
Scenario: admin users can publish documents
  Given a "admin" user exists and is signed in
  And the following categories exist:
    | name            |
    | Category 1      |
  And the following documents exist:
    | name            |  id  |
    | Test Document 1 |   1  |
  And I goto "/admin/documents"
  When I toggle publish document
  And I wait for index
  Then Document "Test Document 1" should be published
  And I should see "Document published successfully!"
```

Result:

```
Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/admin_features/document.feature:135 # Scenario: admin users can publish documents.
```

I tried to debug and i'm getting the output as expected ie, Document published successfully! but i dunno why the test failed after the scenario is successful. I think its realted to some config issue.

Comment: Which one is line 135?

Comment: Line 135 is Scenario: admin users can publish documents.... Actually when i debugged the scenario step by step, i'm getting the result as expected.  I'm able to see "Document published successfully!" in the test environment. I think its something related to @javascript on top of the code....

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail

Comment: i think so, otherwise why its failing after the scenario is passing...

Comment: Then you may want to try the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the scenario was failing.... Actually i degraded cucumber from 2.0.0 to 1.3.8 and it showed me the exact error. Anyways thanks Mark