# Capybara with js driver doesn't generate select options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a test that should select a patient from my list of patients. And if I run the feature test without `js: true` it works perfectly fine.

The problem is, that after I select the patient I also have to execute a change javascript event. If I use any js driver (be it selenium or capybara-webkit) my tests fail stating:

```
Unable to find option "Patient #1"
```

I tried removing DatabaseCleaner and the solutions from the question [Capybara with :js => true causes test to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail).

```
RSpec.feature "Select patient", type: :feature do
  background do
    create(:patient)
    login_as create(:user)
    visit root_path 
  end

  scenario "User selects a created patient", js: true do
    select("Patient #1", from: 'clinical_event_patient_id')
  end
end
```

I also tried setting `js: true` for the `background` and so far I had no success.

Comment: Are you sure that option is on the view? Did you tried to use save_and_open_page or save_screenshot to take a look on your page?
If you have a js logic to show this dropdown, sometimes happens a time gap between the select and the logic to show the dropdown on acceptance tests.

Comment: I used selenium to open the browser and pyr to pause it. The select menu was there along with the prompt selection, but other options weren't present.

Comment: Please show your database cleaner configuration - you'll need to be using truncation for tests with js: true

Comment: As I already stated in my question I tried removing database cleaner completely with no success as well as the proposed solutions shown on the internet (with js:true). The record (patient) does get created, it just doesn't get put in the select option.

Comment: You don't want to remove database cleaner, it's necessary. how do you know the patient is created and accessible in the apps thread?  If you are using transaction based testing the records will appear to be created in the test thread but will never actually be written to the database and hence won't be available in the app thread  So as I asked please show your config

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the select wasn't filled yet when Capybara tried to select this option, since Capybara 2 a smart waiting algorithm is implemented which waits for a default time of 2 seconds before throwing an exception that an element wasn't found.

You can increase this time to 5 seconds for example and see if the element is now loaded or not

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
```

Reference: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Afind

Also try using `page.select`

```
page.select("Patient #1", from: 'clinical_event_patient_id')
```

Another thing it's a good practice not to use static ids in your tests if they were for objects you just created `Patient #1` to avoid the issues of whether a previous records were deleted or not, so in your `background` block add

```
@patient = create(:patient)
```

then in your select

```
page.select("Patient ##{@patient.id}", from: 'clinical_event_patient_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the static ids, but your proposed solution makes no change. The strange thing it, that the patient record does get created, but with js: true for some reason it doesn't get put in the select.

Comment: If you added `save_and_open_page` at the end of your test do u see the select filled at the html produced? Can you also post the code where you are filling the select field with the patients