# rspec test fails to enable javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, rspec-rails

I have the next test with rspec and selenium:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Creating an student" do
  context "When an student visit the sign_up page" do
    scenario "Should be able to create an student" do
      state = FactoryGirl.create(:state)
      city = FactoryGirl.create(:city, state: state)
      institution = FactoryGirl.create(:institution)
      visit root_path
      .........
```

The devise function to register is this:

```
def new 
  @institutions = Institution.all.order(:name)
  @states = State.all
  @cities = City.all
  super
end
```

when I search in my controller the States and Cities, I found this, but when I enable javascript

```
scenario "Should be able to create an student", js: true do
```

the States and Cities return nil.

## Update 1

My spec_helper file is this:

```
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end⋅

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end⋅

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end⋅
end
```

I do not know why this happens.

Comment: what does your spec_helper file look like?  Do you do something different in the database when it is on?

Comment: I don't change nothing in the database.

Comment: I'm guessing that your test is not booting up properly.  I don't think `:chrome` is a valid `javascript_driver`.  You need to use something like selenium.  see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver

Comment: when I run the test with `js:true` open a window of chrome, but not render the states and cities

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me.  Your spec_helper configuration is wrong.  Remove the line `Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome` and ensure `gem "selenium-webdriver"` is in your Gemfile.  Then it might work.

Comment: I found this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178120/capybara-with-js-true-causes-test-to-fail), and it works for me. Thanks